# Not able to stop location updates with fused location APIs

Tags: android, location, fusedlocationproviderapi

Hi I am developing small android application in which I am trying to get location updates using fused location updates. I tried it in following way:

```
private void processStartLocation() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    updateBooleanSharedPreference(this, "isLocationUpdatesOn", true);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, locationPendingIntent);

    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        lat = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
        lon = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        time = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date(mLastLocation.getTime()));
        updateUI();
    }
}

private void processStopLocation() {

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationPendingIntent);
}
```

So everything is working fine. I am able to receive my updates. But when I try to stop updates I got following issue:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlh.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzli.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd.removeLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
```

Am I doing anything wrong. Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: When/where do you call `processStopLocation()`?

Comment: I tried start updates first which is inside onConnect and then after some time I called processStopLocation.

Comment: Do you get location updates at least before you try to cancel updates? Did you implement the `onLocationChanged` callback in your code and is this where you get your updates?

Comment: Check this tutorial here and see if you missed anything -- http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/

Comment: Hi Tasos in this example update listener is activity it self. In my case I am listening for updates inside service and they giving back to activity via broadcast.

Comment: The principle is the same regardless if its an activity or a service.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing that the error complaints about removing all location updates for the given pending intent (`locationPendingIntent`) because the `GoogleApiClient` is not connected - perhaps you should check for its connection status before making the call:

```
private void processStopLocation() {
    if(mGoogleApiClient !=null){
       LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
    else{
     //no need to stop updates - we are no longer connected to location service anyway
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried above solution. But it is simply bypassing the process of stopping location updates. In background inside my receiver I am still getting updates.

Comment: Your Service/Activity implements `LocationListener`, right? So perhaps try stopping location updates by passing the listener instead of the locationPendingIntent. See updated answer.

Comment: yes you have to pass listener and set its value null so u can stop the call back

Answer (score 0):

Cannot see where or when you are calling processStopLocation() but that error generally means your 'mGoogleApiClient' object used in processStopLocation() has lost reference to the connected Google Api Client Object. Maybe a setter for the Google Api Client object in processStartLocation() and getter in processStopLocation() could work. Again without knowing exactly when the update start process and when the stop process is called it's hard to pin point the problem

Comment: Hi Vikrant thank you for replay. Is there any way to maintain mGoogleAPiClient reference. Either store some where or else can I get connected object reference. I am facing same issue if I kill application from background and launch it again. Then try again for stoping service which running in background. There also I need to pass mGoogleApiClient

Comment: Like I said use a set() and get() method on the object. That should sort you out

Comment: On second thought, if you are calling the processStopLocation() from an external class or service using a new object of the class in contrast to the object used to call processStartLocation(), that could be the reason the reference is getting lost. Either way, using a get and set on the object through a separate class will definitely maintain the reference.